# Use match stem in wildcard in makefile

Tags: makefile, build, gnu-make

Makefile like this

```
list-%: $(wildcard src/modules/%/*.ts)
    echo '?' $? - '@' $@ - '%' $% - '<' $< - '^' $^ - '+' $+ - '|' $| - '*' $*
```

But the dependency not works as expected. The output of `make list-test` is

```
echo '?'  - '@' list-test - '%'  - '<'  - '^'  - '+'  - '|'  - '*' test
? - @ list-test - % - < - ^ - + - | - * test
```

If change to `$(wildcard src/modules/test/*.ts)`, then the output become

```
echo '?' src/modules/test/index.ts - '@' list-test - '%'  - '<' src/modules/test/index.ts - '^' src/modules/test/index.ts - '+' src/modules/test/index.ts - '|'  - '*' test
? src/modules/test/index.ts - @ list-test - % - < src/modules/test/index.ts - ^ src/modules/test/index.ts - + src/modules/test/index.ts - | - * test
```

How can I make this `$(wildcard src/modules/%/*.ts)` work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do it, using [Secondary Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Secondary-Expansion). It allows a second expansion of the prerequisite(s) *after* `%` has been matched to a string:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:

list-%: $$(wildcard src/modules/%/*.ts)
    echo '?' $? - '@' $@ - '%' $% - '<' $< - '^' $^ - '+' $+ - '|' $| - '*' $*
```

**Note the `$$`.** In the read-in phase, `$$(wildcard src/modules/%/*.ts)` expands to `$(wildcard src/modules/%/*.ts)`. Then Make chooses this pattern rule as a way to build `list-foo`, and in the second expansion `$(wildcard src/modules/foo/*.ts)` expands to a list of filenames.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I make this $(wildcard src/modules/%/*.ts) work ?

Sadly, you can't. The `%` works only in a very restricted way in prerequisites. It is applied as a last pseudo-wildcard after all `make` functions have already been evaluated, thus there is no interaction of patterns and functions - I could think maybe of some recursive construct but this is way over the top for such a simple task. Instead you could get away with programmed dependencies:

```
MODULES := a b c

all: $(MODULES:%=list-%)
        @echo DONE

# generate dependencies programmatically:
$(foreach m,$(MODULES),$(eval list-$(m): $(wildcard src/modules/$(m)/*.ts)))

list-%:
        @echo $^
        @echo $@
```

Notice that it is perfectly legal for vanilla targets to have the dependency list spread out over several target:prerequisite statements and the recipe in another rule. The only caveat is that if you have a non-existent module in your list, then it will execute this module with an empty prerequisite list and fail with a possibly hard to understand error message.